# Why don't I see an object in UV Editing?

Tags: objects, uv-image-editor

Default:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UV-Editing:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Files: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/64a6oroq8tpf2xs/Fence3.blend?dl=0) и [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5du3bv4fghke4xk/Fence3.blend1?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply turn on both layers, now only 1 is active.

[image]

Comment: Can I combine this 2 layers in 1?

Comment: Activate layer 2, select all, press M and click on layer 1: everything will be moved to layer 1.